# Game Center Error

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

I am following a tutorial here . [Multiplayer Game iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22)

I am using following code from above tutorial for Match Making

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];    
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
```

When I search for other players using Play Now option, the `GKMatchmakerViewController` dismissed immediately delegating `matchmakerViewController:didFailWithError` with following error.

```
Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be 
completed due to an error communicating with the server." UserInfo=0x2081d8d0
{GKServerStatusCode=5001, NSUnderlyingError=0x2086c560 "The operation couldn’t be 
completed. (GKServerErrorDomain error 5001.)", NSLocalizedDescription=The requested
operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.}
```

I have not been able to figure why is it happening so. The same code was previously able to search and find appropriate players but failed when fetching player aliases using

```
[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:match.playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
```

with 'Could not communicate to server' error.

The code however, works fine on simulator.

Comment: Just now started happening to me a couple hours ago after coding all night. Perhaps the servers are down?

Comment: Perhaps, because it seems to working fine now. :(

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got

> Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not
>   be completed due to an error communicating with the server."
>   UserInfo=0x17007e4c0 {GKServerStatusCode=5001,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed
>   due to an error communicating with the server.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x170050140 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (GKServerErrorDomain error 5001.)

I think this is sandbox.gc.apple.com problem..
this question is one year but apple still have this problem sometime

Wish apple fix this soon.

I try on iPod touch and I got

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo=0x176bec90
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://sandbox.gc.apple.com/WebObjects/GKInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://sandbox.gc.apple.com/WebObjects/GKInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

Comment: yes the issue was merely due to servers being unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem (GKServerStatusCode=5001) when sending new high score using reportScoreWithCompletionHandler.

In sandbox mode all is OK, but AppStore version has this issue on all devices where sandbox mode was enabled (iOS 8.2 / 8.3). But I can see data from other users in leaderboards. Looks like this is actually bug on Apple's side.